# Remix: how is gas price determined?

Tags: gas, gas-price

When I send a transaction from remix, how does it set the gas price for the transaction (not gas cost / limit)?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on client you are using to broadcast your transaction. Most of them choose the standard gas price at the time the transaction is about to be sent. MyCrypto and Metamask do this, for example.

Comment: ok that's helpful - how do they retrieve the 'standard gas price at the time the transaction is sent' ?

Comment: ethgasstation.info has an API that provides this number based on the current network

Comment: and which software part is querying this api? geth? or remix?

Answer (score 1):

Remix in particularly uses [ethgasstation.info](https://ethgasstation.info/), but many wallets such as metamask will use `eth_gasPrice` from the node they are connected to

Comment: now I'm confused - the other answer stated it's the client that choses it (I thought in this case the client would be geth, not remix?)

Comment: ethgasstation and geth would both provide an estimated gas price, but the client is free to update it